# PHP Duplicate log entries with file_put_contents when using header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');

Tags: php, audio, cross-browser, mp3

I am using php to play a mix of mp3 files. I keep having an issue when I load the page, it executes my logging functionality twice. This results in duplicate entries in the log. I simplified my code to post on here.

When I execute the following php file, it plays the "test.mp3" in the browser perfectly. I get no errors in my error_log.

```
    <?php
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

print readfile("test.mp3");

$logentry = date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A") . " Play Successful\n";

file_put_contents('play.log', $logentry, FILE_APPEND);
    
?>
```

Looking in my play.log file after loading the above php once, I get this:

```
Monday 24th of August 2020 03:57:10 AM Play Successful
Monday 24th of August 2020 03:57:10 AM Play Successful
```

Duplicate entries.
To further isolate, I commented out the "header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');" line and the webpage loads the binary mp3 file visually (a bunch of random character) as expected. When I inspect the log file I see that it make a single entry as it should.

Any ideas why using "header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');" causes the double-dipping?
This occurs when loading the script in Chrome and Edge. Using Safari I get tipple entries. IE I get a single entry as it should be.

How can I make this work reliably across all browsers to have accurate logs?

Comment: If it's client-dependent, then it's either MME probing, prefetching, or audio handler buffering. Why the dance-around with the php script anyway?

Comment: The script I am working on will combine multiple MP3s from pre-recorded sources to play seamlessly in a browser. I put this simplified version here just to help others replicate my issues. I am now working on making a parent php script that makes the log entries and selects the mp3 files and passes it off to a second php script that will play them (and let the MME probing, prefetching, or audio handler buffering not impact the logging).